# Как отсортировать HashMap

Tags: java

Как отсортировать HashMap по убывания количества повторений, то есть по Integer ? Если у кого-то есть реализация, буду очень благодарен)

```
String string = "101010001010101010";
int rate = 8;//8,16,24
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
int counter = 0;
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    counter++;
    buffer.append(string.charAt(i));
    if (counter == rate) {
        counter = 0;
        Integer frequency = hashMap.get(buffer.toString());
        hashMap.put(buffer.toString(), frequency == null ? 1 : frequency + 1);
        buffer = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
System.out.println("????? ????????? ?????? - "+ rate + " ?????:: ");
String[] arrayKey = hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);

for (int k = 0; k < arrayKey.length; k++)
{
    System.out.println( arrayKey[k] + " - " + hashMap.get(arrayKey[k]));
}
```

Comment: Сортировка хэш мапы. Странно звучит.

Answer (score 3):

Отсортировать записи из `Map` по значениям можно следующим образом, используя Java 8 Stream API:

```
 List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = map.entrySet().stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Если нужна сортировка в обратном порядке - чуть-чуть добавится кода:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Integer>, Integer>
        comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Здесь записи сохраняются в список как есть, однако можно их вывести, оставить только ключи/значения или что-нибудь ещё, по необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```
String[] arrayKey = hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
Integer arr[] = new Integer[arrayKey.length];

for (int k = 0; k < arrayKey.length; k++) {
    Log.i("log__1", " arrayKey[k] - hashMap.get(buffer.toString()) - " + arrayKey[k] + " - " + hashMap.get(arrayKey[k]));

    arr[k] = hashMap.get(arrayKey[k]);
}

Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
for(int i = 0; i <  arr.length; i++) {
    Log.i("log__1", arr[i] + "  ");
}
```